# can only receive one message on a channel

Tags: go

I've created a global channel, and am sending messages to it whenever a new event occurs inside of ExampleNewWatcher. The first time an event occurs, the message is getting received in the receiving end of the channel. However, the second time an event occurs, I am not receiving a message in the receiving end of the channel.

```
var messages = make(chan string)
func ExampleNewWatcher(){
  watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
  if err != nil{
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer watcher.Close(0
  done := make(chan bool)
  go func(){
     for {
        select{
           case event := <- watcher.Events:
              if event.Op&fsnotify.Write == fsnotify.Write{
                 log.Println("this logs twice if I create two write events")
                 messages <- "this message only gets sent once even if I create two events"
              }
           case err := <- watcher.Errors:
               log.Println("error", err)
        }

     }
  }()
  err = watcher.Add("/tmp/watchedfile")
  <-done
}
func Websock(ws *websocket.Conn){
   msg := <-messages
   log.Println("only one message arrives, even if I create for two events", msg)
   err := websocket.Message.Send(ws, msg)

}
func main(){
 go ExampleNewWatcher() //for some reason, the server doesn't run unless I prefix a go routine to this watcher function, but that's another issue ...

  http.Handle("/websock", websocket.Handler(Websock))
 log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))

}
```

Comment: How do you call `waitForMessage`? In your posted code, you don't call it at all.

Comment: @PaulHankin I updated the OP to show how `waitForMessage` is called (i.e it's websocket handler). Note, I changed the name of the func in the edited code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WebSock function need to include a receive loop to receive more than one message. Otherwise, your function will terminate and the websocket connection will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

@Mickaël Rémond is right. Modify your `Websock` function to something like:

```
func Websock(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    for {
        msg := <-messages
        log.Println("only one message arrives, even if I create for two events", msg)
        if err := websocket.Message.Send(ws, msg); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
```